Closing an opening in a upstairs concrete floor
I have a concrete floor (made from hollow core beam and blocks), on an upstairs level, where there is an opening that was originally intended for a staircase (from the previous owners). Since the staircase will never be built there, I want to close it.
I could easily close it with a wooden structure, but I'm not sure what kind of flooring I'll utlimately use upstairs. Since the existing floor is made of concrete and I may want to use tiles at some point, I'd much prefer to close it with concrete, so that it the entire floor base is consistent and can eventually receive a tile finish.
The opening is about 2.8m by 1.15m. It is supported on both sides (along the longest sides, obviously): one side is supported by a cinder blocks wall (20 cm thick), and the other side by a ~60cm adobe/mud wall (typical from our region, that's an old farm). Both are load bearing, and can support much more than they currently do. So, basically, the span of the slab to create is just 1.15m.
Now, I don't really know what is the required slab thickness required for this, and the amount of rebar required. I initially thought I'd be safe with a 15cm slab with a wire mesh, with wires and some additional thicker rebars inserted in the existing support walls/slab and sealed with chemical compound (and preparing a flat formwork underneath). However, that's actually quite some volume of concrete to prepare and pour by myself (about half a cubic meter). I would prefer minimizing the amount of concrete being used, since I'll need to pour it from upstairs, and I don't have an easy way to bring concrete upstairs (basically just a ladder).
So I'm thinking of having a more complicated formwork that will create beams with 1.15m length, evenly spaced along the opening (using rebar cages along the beams, and some wire mesh on top), and pour that, which may reduce the total amount of concrete.
For example, If I build six 12x12cm square slots in the formwork, and plan for a 8cm thick surface like this:

This somewhat results in having 12x20cm beams, and requires only 0.35 m3 of concrete. I save about 30% of concrete buckets, which I'm sure I'll appreciate. All that being actually thicker than what I'd overall do with a wooden structure (some table I have says 50x150mm beams are already way overkill, but with a slightly reduced spacing, though).
Is it a good idea? Is it enough? Can I go even smaller? How do I size all this properly? Any additional advice?

Regarding your section above, 8 cm is nowhere near thick enough for a slab, let alone provide enough cover for rebar.  What is the design of the existing concrete slab?

@Huesmann Hard to tell, it was already there. But it is made from hollow core blocks and beams, covered with a poured slab that probably includes a mesh. Total height is probably ~20cm. As for wether what I plan to do is sufficient, I'm suprised of what you say. It is just ~40cm between joists, and you can find manhole covers suitable for pedestrians made of reinforced concrete, that are 8cm thick and have more than 70cm diameter! How do they achieve that? Also regarding rebar cover: typically, blocks and beams floors must have at least 4cm poured over the mesh, but that can be enough.

The following addresses the "Any additional advice" part of the question, since I know next to nothing about concrete. This pursues the "I could easily close it with a wooden structure" idea.
It appears that wood is deprecated in your planning because of possible issues causing tile to not be usable. However, tile is successfully installed on wooden subfloors with suitable intermediate materials. So I deduce that flex may be the concern you may have about a wood-based plug to the floor hole.
Flex in a wood platform can be removed in multiple ways. Start with the wood support ring around the opening, then:

Increase the number of joists across the opening. Double or triple the number of joists across the 1.5m width of the opening, until the flex is down enough.
Make the plug as a torsion box, instead of just joists and a subfloor plate. A torsion box has a plate underneath as well as on top, and the plates are glued to the joists and support ring. Locking the plates and joists together makes the compression and tension stresses all balance out, making an extremely inflexible platform.

There may be other methods to stiffen a wood platform. But you should be able to make a wood platform stiff enough to support tile and not have that portion of the otherwise concrete tiled floor feel different.
